# Password Length Validation always triggers regardless of password length

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, passwords

I'm trying to add password length validations to a form that creates a model, the artist. The form has  three fields: name, email, and password. There is no password confirmation field. I added validations to all three fields. Both name and email validations return the respective errors when I fill in those fields wrong and both gives no errors when the fields are filled in correctly. However no matter what length of a password I fill in for the password field, it always gives an error "password is too short."

code so far for validations

File: Artist.rb

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
# attr_accessible :artist_name, :route_name

include UsersHelper

has_many :band_members
has_many :users, through: :band_members
has_many :events
has_many :performers
has_many :soundcloud_embeds
has_many :petitions

has_secure_password #validations: false

validate :should_not_have_profanities
validates :artist_name, presence: true
validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: {          case_sensitive: false }
validates :password, length: 6..50
before_create { generate_route_name if route_name.blank? }
before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
```

What I tried so far:

switching :password to :password_digest. This didn't work because It's password digest != password.

adding 'on: create' to 'validates :password'. This didn't seem to have any effect on fixing the problem.

Comment: I dont think `within` is required. Give this a try: `validates :password, length: 6..50`

Comment: I removed the within, the problem is still the same as before

Comment: Ok, I dont see anything else that's obviously wrong here. Have you verified that the password is actually coming through and is being set on the object in the controller layer?

Comment: yes after checking the console, the object is not being created because of the validations.

Comment: Can you post the params hash from the request?

Comment: `Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Q0nmOAwpmP/MHBDJs+CH5gwayBVKepo3vbxxIix6P/Y=", "artist"=>{"artist_name"=>"dfd", "email"=>"dfdfd@dflkajdsf.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}`

Answer (score 0):

I think it should just be `in`, not `within`...

```
validates :password, length: { in: 6..50 }
```

See here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#length

Comment: Are you using strong_parameters and allowing the password attribute?

Comment: do you mean by having this method in the object controller?

`def artist_params
    params.require(:artist).permit(:artist_name, :route_name, :password, :email, :background_image)
  end`

Comment: yeah, and then your `update` action is using `artist_params` instead of `params[:artist]`?

Answer (score 0):

I often like using Regex for character validation. Difficult to learn but helps a lot. For a string length, you'll need something in your file like this:

```
VALID_PASSWORD_REGEX = /[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,16}/

validates format: { with: VALID_PASSWORD_REGEX }
```